# Styling input with jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok I have the css sorted:

Now to style the input box ( but this isnt working ) any suggestions. Think my js is messed up.
The html element:

```
<input name="latLng" class="latLng" id="latLng2" type="text" disabled />
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input.latLng').locationPicker({
    width: "500px",
    height: "20px",
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10
    });
});
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong please.

Comment: To format, select your code and click the `101010` button at the top, or indent it over 4 spaces manually :)

Comment: Or select the code and `ctrl+K`

Comment: Or type backquotes (`) around the snippet to do inline code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set styles, use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for the styling of the element and call your plugin separately, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input.latLng').css({
    width: "500px",
    height: "20px",
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10
    }).locationPicker();
});
```

Or, a bit shorter:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input.latLng').css({
      width: 500,
      height: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: 10,
      padding: 10
    }).locationPicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, will try that ( I am trying to get the hang of SO )

Comment: Ok now code is: <pre><script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    $('input.latLng').css({
      width: 300,
      height: 18,
   padding: '4px',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: '3px',
      padding: '3px'
    }).locationPicker();
});

</script></pre> all seems to work fine, just rounded corners arent really showing ( chosen 3px to match other form elements )